# Login modal view troubles

Tags: objective-c, authentication, modalviewcontroller

I have a main login VC, where the user can select to login with facebook, register an account, or login with their created account. If I click on register or login, they will segue from that main VC to the appropriate register VC, or register VC, respectively. This is using an `UINavigationController`.

When my app starts, it immediately shows the login screen. When the user successfully logins (either with Facebook or account), it pushes an items `UITableViewController`. So the login is not being presented modally. I am working with storyboards, and in Interface Builder, my root VC is my login selection screen.

Now, here's the issue: I'd like to make the whole login process modal instead of pushing when the login is complete. So the app should do the following:

a) user opens app, app checks to see if user is logged in. If so, present items table VC.

b) if user not logged in, modally present login and let user choose what to login with.

c) user logs in, then dismiss VC modally (slide it down) and show the items table VC.

I'm very confused with this approach and how to tackle it, because although it does seem natural, I've been using a wrong approach, which was to push the item VC after the login happens.

When the user signs out, I'd like to slide up the login screen, and after they login again, go back to the item table VC (not the settings VC which houses my log out button).

I've seen many apps have this approach, so I assume it's standard. What would a good way be to implement this? I know how to present VC's modally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [View Controller Programming Guide: Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html):

> When you present a modal view controller, the system creates a
>   relationship between the view controller that did the presenting and
>   the view controller that was presented.

So you need to make the items table VC as the root view controller, and check whether user is logged in or not in the first place in that items table VC. You can even use NSNotificationCenter to observe user logging in/out.

If user is logged in, you can keep the items table VC there, and if he/she is not, you can present the login VC modally.

After that you can just follow the scenarios you have described above.